# Asp.Net image will not display

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, file-upload

I have been trying to troubleshoot for a while now and I officially give up. Would someone help me figure out what is wrong with the following code. I am uploading an image and then I want to display it.

This is my upload image Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
 Try
  FileUpload1.SaveAs("C:/BegASPNET/test/Pictures/Profile/" + FileUpload1.FileName)
  Label1.Text = "File name: " + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName
 Catch ex As Exception
    Label1.Text = "ERROR: " & ex.Message.ToString()
  End Try
Else
  Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file."
End If


Using myEntities As New DatabaseEntities()
  Dim pic As Picture
  pic = New Picture()
  pic.UserID = Profile.ID
  pic.ImageUrl = "~/Pictures/Profile/" + FileUpload1.FileName
  myEntities.AddToPictures(pic)
  myEntities.SaveChanges()
End Using
End Sub
```

And the .aspx file:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
```

And then to display the image, my Code Behind is:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
Handles Me.Load   

Using myProfile As New DatabaseEntities()
  Dim prof = (From p In myProfile.UserProfiles
             Where p.UserID = Profile.ID
             Select p).SingleOrDefault()
  dFNameLabel.Text = prof.FirstName
  dLNameLabel.Text = prof.LastName
  dDOBLabel.Text = prof.DOB
  dGenderLabel.Text = prof.Gender
  dEmailLabel.Text = prof.Email
  Dim pic = (From pi In myProfile.Pictures
            Where pi.UserID = Profile.ID AndAlso pi.picDefault = True
            Select pi.ImageUrl).SingleOrDefault
End Using
End Sub
```

And my .aspx is:

```
<asp:Image ID="ImageUrl" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>'/>
```

I verified that the image url is in the database and that the image is saved to a file. If I hard code an absolute path in the image control of the .aspx file the picture will display. But, it won't work with the above '<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>' code. I have no idea where the problem lies so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is when you are trying to save the image,

This statement

```
  FileUpload1.SaveAs("C:/BegASPNET/test/Pictures/Profile/" + FileUpload1.FileName)
```

should be like...

```
  FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Pictures/Profile/") + FileUpload1.FileName)
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammad! I tried your suggestion but the problem persists.

Comment: What you are getting in ImageURL?

Comment: There is only one record in the Picture table and in the ImageUrl column there is:  ~/Pictures/Profile/Aunt Yolanda.jpg and the picdefault column is:  True

Comment: Is this work for you, if you set in this way  pic.ImageUrl = "~/Pictures/Profile/" + FileUpload1.FileName ?

Comment: The path string is getting stored in the Picture table. Is there a better way to save it?

Comment: I can think one issue, this is not caontaining value '<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %> , you need to sure that you are getting value in ImageUrl ?

Comment: You got me thinking, so I had the '<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>' go to a label and I got nothing. For some reason it does not work on this one page of my project (I have it all over other pages). I finally got it to work by using:  Image1.ImageUrl = picture.ImageUrl in the code behind and eliminating the '<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>' from the .aspx. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
private string ConfigFileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileName"];
string strAppPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "ProductImage";

string strImg = ConfigFileName + Request.Params["ModuleID"].ToString() + ".jpg";
fileupload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(strAppPath + "//" + strImg);
```